# Geoserver SLD error

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld

Could you give me an advice with this sld file https://pastebin.com/xFTrsKni

I get this error when I Validate:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM

I also get this error from the wms file when I save and Layer Preview:

```
  java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM
```

Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an SLD file so GeoServer can't parse it.